# javascript calculate operator sum

Tags: javascript

i have stuck on javascript operation if i calculate 10,000 + 60,000 the result 70,000 ,
but when i write down bigger numbers eg 1,000,000 + 2,245,000 the result is 3,245

here is the function

```
function calculate() {
        
  var uang_cash = parseInt(document.getElementById('uang_cash').value.replace(',',''));
  var uang_tf   = parseInt(document.getElementById('uang_tf').value.replace(',',''));
      
 document.getElementById('uang_saya2').value = parseFloat(uang_cash)+parseFloat(uang_tf);
}
```

**in lower number its true**
[image]

**in bigger number its false**
[image]

if i write down bigger numbers `1,000,000 + 2,245,000` the result is `3,245,000`
is there something wrong in calling the data type?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `replace()` by default doesn't look for *all* occurrences of the searched string but the *first* occurrence, so for the large numbers with two commas, the second one gets ignored.

```js
const value = '1,000,000';
console.log('value:', value);
console.log('After replace():', value.replace(',', ''));
console.log('Parsed:', parseInt(value.replace(',', '')));
```

You need to use the `/g` flag of RegEx to solve it:

```js
const value = '1,000,000';
console.log('value:', value);
console.log('After replace():', value.replace(/,/g, ''));
console.log('Parsed:', parseInt(value.replace(/,/g, '')));
```